# Browser back button doesn't work when content is loaded into an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, browser, back-button

I have a javascript function using which I display some content when the user clicks on a link.

```
function showContent(filename){
  var oldcontent = $('#content').html();
  var srcUrl = getSourceUrl(filename);
  $('#content').html(oldcontent + '<iframe style="width:100%;height=100%;display:block;" src="'+srcUrl+'" />');
}
```

Since the content is loaded into an IFrame, the URL doesn't get changed and I can not go back to the previous page where the link was using browser's back button. I am a newbie and I tried to do something(silly experiment) like this. i.e. appending a '#page2' to the url but then when user clicks on the back button, nothing happens.

```
var oldcontent = $('#content').html();
var srcUrl = getSourceUrl(filename);
location.href = location.href + '#page2';
$('#content').html(oldcontent + '<iframe style="width:100%;height=100%;display:block;" src="'+srcUrl+'" />');
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong with this and how to enable the back button functionality?

Comment: Look into `hashchange` event in older browser and `history.pushstate` in new browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hash Test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='message-container'></div>
  </body>
  <script>
    var messages = ["Hello. Click anywhere on the page.", "How are you?", "I hope you're fine.", "Have a nice day and hit the back button."];
    var currentMessage = 0;
    var lastMessage = messages.length - 1;

    $(document).click(function() {
      nextMessage();
    });

    function nextMessage() {
      if (currentMessage < lastMessage) {
        currentMessage++;
        updateHash();
      }
    }

    function displayMessage() {
      $("#message-container").text(messages[currentMessage]);
    }

    function updateHash() {
      window.location.hash = "#message" + currentMessage;
    }

    $(window).on("hashchange", function() {
      if (/message\d+/.test(window.location.hash)) {
        currentMessage = window.location.hash.match(/message(\d+)/)[1];
        displayMessage();
      }
    });

    updateHash();
  </script>
</html>
```